# Built-in Like Button - Facebook SDK 3.0

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-like

Does anybody happen to know a good tutorial on placing the ‘I like it’ button into the application?
I’m especially interested in Facebook SDK 3.0 and the so-called Built-in Like button.

So far, I’ve been searching through google and stackoverflow but I haven't found anything about SDK 3.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Publishing a built-in like is very similar to publishing a custom Open Graph *action*. The best resource for learning about publishing built-in likes is Facebook's reference page:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/likes/

Comment: Do you know how can I make this HTTP POST request in objective-c?`curl -X POST \
     -F 'access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN' \
     -F 'object=OG_OBJECT_URL' \
     https://graph.facebook.com/[User FB ID]/og.likes` I want like some page or image...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991789/iphone-objective-c-executing-curl-based-actions-in-objective-c

Answer (score 2):

Please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5837036/445312) regarding likes and [this post](http://angelolloqui.blogspot.co.uk/2010/11/facebook-like-button-on-ios.html) to see an alternative of adding a like button.

Ideally you could create a html iframe that links to the page. obviously this would open up the webpage to the link of the facebook like button. atm i believe that's how temple run achieve this. does the trick. They're getting many likes from users directed from the ios app temple run itself.