# Ionic AngularJS Facebook like button for Facebook page

Tags: ios, angularjs, facebook, ios-simulator, ionic-framework

this code is working when i run in the browser. But not works in iPhone simulator.

I checked in the console, there is no error.

My goal is to add a Facebook like button which points to my Facebook Page in the ionic app. I try to implement using the basic code from the [Facebook developers site](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button). But this is also not working.

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/1c5cWB?p=preview)

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="like.html">
  <div ng-if="pluginOn" onrender="rendered()" class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
</script>
```

Comment: Are you building a app which runs in the simulator (including like button) or do you access a website in mobile safari?

Comment: no its an iPhone app. For development i am checking in the simulator.

Comment: does this help you? Please mark my answer as right if it is?

Answer (score 2):

#### It won't work for native apps because:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/like-button/ is not supported yet. You will need a HOST to make it work. Thats why it will work on WebBrowser (Hosted application).

It can be done with the graph API: [Built-in Like Button - Facebook SDK 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915269/built-in-like-button-facebook-sdk-3-0)

In that way you have to create it on your own. There are a lot of approaches to do this. One is to do a POST on:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/og.likes?access_token=FB_ACCESS_TOKEN&object=URL_TO_LIKE.

Hint: You will need `FB.init()` & `FB.getLoginStatus()` and a `accessToken`.

If you are using cordova/phoneGap you can use https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will try to implement like you told and i am not using phoneGap. I am using Ionic and Angularjs.