# sending the api key value (production key) through http request in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

With the Reference to these Posts 
    [Objective-C equivalent of curl request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451205/objective-c-equivalent-of-curl-request) ,[Executing curl based actions in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991789/iphone-objective-c-executing-curl-based-actions-in-objective-c)
i tried Below Code for my Example
I have the example data like below

```
curl --get  'https://www.example.com/xyz' \
     --user 'API_KEY:API_SECRET' \
     --data 'app_id=APP_ID' \
     --data 'metrics=users' \
     --data 'dimensions=day,new_device' \
     --data-urlencode 'conditions={"day":["between","2013-04-01","2013-04-07"]}'
```

How can I retrieve the data if I have the api key(production key),? and also how can I retrieve the data of users by using the above parameters? 
    I tried doing it something like this , to pass the  parameter to retrieve the data through the url .

```
-(void)doit
{
    NSString *userName =@"abc@v.com";
    NSString *password =@"cvbnm";

    NSError *myError = nil;


    NSMutableString *loginString = (NSMutableString*)[@"" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@:%@", userName, password];
    NSLog(@"loginstring=%@",loginString);


    NSString *accept = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"application/example"];

    NSLog(@"accept %@",accept);
    NSString *authHeader = [@"Basic " stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@", loginString];
    NSLog(@"auth header =%@",authHeader);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://example.bnm/query"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
    request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setValue:@"users" forKey:@"metrics"];
[request setValue:@"value of api key" forKey:@"API_KEY"];
[request setValue:@"day" forKey:@"dimension"];
[request setValue:@"{"day":["between","2013-04-01","2013-04-07"]}" forKey:@"conditions"];

 NSError *error;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSLog(@"data : %@",data);

    NSString *result = [NSString stringWithCString:[data bytes] length:[data length]];
     NSLog(@"result = %@",result);
}
```

But something went wrong and 'm not getting the proper response. Please do help me with this , please let me know how to fix it , any help will be really great , please let me know if you need more information

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your lines that say
    [request setValue: forKey:];

Those don't actually set the request body, what you need to do is something like this:

```
NSString *stringData = @"app_id=APP_ID&metrics=users&foo=bar";
NSData *requestBodyData = [stringData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
request.HTTPBody = requestBodyData;
```

Then try posting that and see if it works for you!

**Edit:**

I also noticed you're not using the authentication, you're just logging `authHeader`

Comment: thank you so much for replying. As you said I have replaced it with what u said.but  'm getting the data as null and result nothing.

Comment: As you said I have edited, but 'm getting the response something like this 2014-04-07 23:25:51.800
 FirstDemo[56329:70b] loginstring=abc@v.com:vmbnm
2014-04-07 23:25:51.800 FirstDemo[56329:70b] accept application/accept
2014-04-07 23:25:51.801 FirstDemo[56329:70b] auth header =Basic abc@v.com:vmbnm
2014-04-07 23:25:51.801 FirstDemo[56329:70b] after request
2014-04-07 23:26:00.449 FirstDemo[56329:70b] data : (null)
2014-04-07 23:26:00.449 FirstDemo[56329:70b] result =

Comment: if data is Nil then you should take a look at the content of the NSError, just put a breakpoint after the response is received or `NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);`, let me know what it says.

Comment: Yeah , the error is something like this :
rror: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo=0x8d6ecc0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://example.bnm/query, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://example.bnm/query, NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost., NSUnderlyingError=0x8b9f280 "The network connection was lost."}

Comment: You're not by any chance using `example.bnm/query` as your URL right ?

Comment: i am already using their sdk for one of my main application" ,this app is to track the userdata ,analytics .we have to make another app for admin tracking

Comment: again, why don't you use their SDK on this app ? it seems that basic requests are confusing you so why go the hard way ? the SDK will handle all the connections, you know ?

Comment: "No sdk is for (creating) analytics not for records ,for recording/tracking the user data , we have to visit localystics  website user portal or we hAve to use these api's" to retrieve the user data

Comment: Is there any other way to retrieve the data ?