# iOS How to create a POST request and redirect it's response into Safari

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a couple of UITextFields in my view and a button.  When the user fills them out and hits the button I would like to create a POST request and open the resulting page in Safari.  I've gotten the request property built and ready to go using this example and others:
[How do I make HTTP post request for getting JSON object in response for iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264140/how-do-i-make-http-post-request-for-getting-json-object-in-response-for-iphone-ap)

However I'm stuck on how to send the request object to safari, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found [this link](http://lists.apple.com/archives/macnetworkprog/2008/Jul/msg00048.html) that may help. The author of it just creates some temporary html file that opens up in safari and then safari sends the POST and gets response...

Comment: This is the best answer so far, but I'm going to hold out for a bit before giving it the thumbs up.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, you cannot actually send an `NSURLRequest` object to Safari. However, you can use `UIWebView`'s `- (void)loadRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request` method to load the request in a `UIWebView`.

If you need the link to open in something resembling a full browser, you could try following [iCode Blog's tutorial on creating a web browser](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/12/19/iphone-coding-learning-about-uiwebviews-by-creating-a-web-browser/).

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping that I wouldn't have to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Check out `(BOOL)[UIApplication openURL:(NSURL *)url]` - [UIApplication](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: This won't actually work because a NSUrl can't contain the request data.